# Object on the stack in C++ - interview question

Tags: c++, oop, stack

Class A has two data members which are instances of class B and class C. Class B needs an instance of class C to be created. We have to create an instance of object A on stack like 'A objA' in main function. 'new' operator should not be used anywhere.no objects on the heap

Basically no objects on the heap. I initially did this using 'new' operator. But the interviewer said like inside only 'A objA' is allowed. Once it is executed, the whole object should be created.

Comment: And what is the problem with this? What did you try?

Comment: i did with using structs for C,B  and A initially. But he was not convinced with the solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the interviewer meant something like the following:

```cpp
struct C { };

struct B {
  B (C & obj) { /* Do something with obj. */ }
};

struct A {
  A ()
    : c_()
    , b_(c_)
  { }

  C c_;
  B b_;
};

int main () {
  A objA;
}
```

The key here is to make sure `A`'s `C`-type member comes before it's `B`-type member. That way you can pass a e.g. reference to `A`'s `c_` to the constructor of the `b_` member.

As you can see, no need for `new` or any kind of heap allocation. Everything is created on the stack.

Comment: Dangerous code. `obj` in `B` can be a reference to a `C` object that has not been constructed yet if the declaration of `c_` is moved below the declaration of `b_` inside `A`.

Comment: That's what compiler warnings are for. It's C++, you can shoot yourself in the foot in a gazillion ways if you are so inclined. E.g. this kind of code becomes completely broken as soon as you start inserting `A`s into an `std::vector` and had `B` store a reference/pointer to the `C` it got in its constructor.

Comment: But I think that's the whole point of the interview question. To learn that the order of declarations is important.

Comment: Right, hence why I specifically state that right under the example code.

Comment: @mfnx I definitely agree, with the right flags you could make the warning an error. Add in the [undefined behavior sanitizer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/ubsan.html) and such bugs should become nearly impossible to make.

Answer (score 1):

There are no conditions on `class C`:

```
struct C{};
```

The only condition on `class B` is that it needs an instance of class `C` to be created:

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(const C&) {}
};
```

And finally, `class A` has 2 members, 1 of type `B` and the other of type `C`:

```
struct A
{
    C _c {};
    B _b { _c };
};
```

We can now create an object of type `A` as you mentioned:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```